# The OutputPath property is not set for project TFS2012

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I have a build in our Team Foundation server which gives this warring:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets
>   (610): The OutputPath property is not set for project
>   'Plugin.DeploymentTool.csproj'.  Please check to make sure that you
>   have specified a valid combination of Configuration and Platform for
>   this project.  Configuration='Release'  Platform='x86'.  You may be
>   seeing this message because you are trying to build a project without
>   a solution file, and have specified a non-default Configuration or
>   Platform that doesn't exist for this project.

I can't find any solution or why i get this error. But then i look at the generated zip file, the Binary folder are empty. I have tried to use the x86, x64 and Any CPU, to se if there are are any difference, which there are not.

If i look into the project file, it looks okay.

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: What configuration have you configured for the build definition to use? Looking at the message, the Build is trying to use x86, and you only have PropertyGroups for AnyCPU.

Comment: @DaveShaw. Then i look a the summary of the build without the configuration, it's using Debug | AnyCPU. but if i configure the configuration if gives. me the error. I the project it's declared to use the Debug | Any CPU.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I have found a solution to the problem, which turns out to be a pretty simple one. 
The default Configuration in TFS Build look like this:
Configuration: Release, Platform: **Any CPU**

But in Visual Studio 2012 it looks like this: 
Configuration: Release, Platform: **AnyCPU**

The solution is to remove the space between Any and CPU in the TFS Build Platform. Now it works perfectly.

**UPDATE**

The issue has been corrected in VS2013.

Comment: I've done that myself on command line builds, I can never remember if it's with or without spaces :). Glad you found it.

Comment: Nice one. I had the same issue.

Comment: I'm still seeing this problem with VS2015 and TFS2013. 
Whether its VS or TFS that's causing the problem I can not say at this point.

Answer (score 14):

For Visual Studio Team Services (was Visual Studio Online) integrated builds, @mortenstarck's answer does the trick as well.  In the variables of your build, specify `anycpu` for `BuildPlatform`.

---

[image: build variables]

---

The variable is referenced in the build step:

[image: build step]

Comment: Can confirm this fixes the issue in VSTS. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

In addition to the other answers, I have noticed this:

1. For building a ***.sln*** (solution), you need the space so it has to be `any cpu` (notice the space).
2. For building a ***.csproj***, you DO NOT need the space so it has to be `anycpu`.